# Split large single column into two columns

Tags: awk, split

I need to split a single column of data in a large file into two columns as follows:

```
A
B           B A
C    ---->  D C
D           F E
E           H G
F
G
H
```

Is there an easy way of doing it with unix shell commands and/or small shell script? awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR%2{s=$0;next} {print $0,s}' file
B A
D C
F E
H G
```

Comment: +1: I take that back. This is more `awkish` than my `awkish` way! `:P`

Comment: thank you! i knew it was an awk statement...if one knows awk like you do. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following awk script:

```
awk 'NR % 2 != 0 {cache=$0}; NR % 2 == 0 {print $0 cache}' data.txt
```

Output:

```
BA
DC
FE
HG
```

It caches the value of odd lines and outputs even lines + appends the cache to them.

Comment: +1: `awkish` way would be `awk 'NR%2{cache=$0}!(NR%2){print $0, cache}' data.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is tagged `awk`, but I just can't stop myself from posting a `sed` solution, since the question left it open for "easy way . . . with unix shell commands":

```
$ sed -n 'h;n;G;s/\n/ /g;p' data.txt
B A
D C
F E
H G
```